# Multiplying out complex numbers in polar form

Tags: linear-algebra

From my Linear Algebra textbook:

$$ z_1z_2 = r_1r_2(\cos{\theta_1} + i \sin\theta_1)(\cos\theta_2 + i \sin\theta_2) \\
       = r_1r_2\big((\cos{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2} - \sin{\theta_1} \sin{\theta_2}) + 
         i(\sin{\theta_1} \cos{\theta_2} + \cos{\theta_1}\sin{\theta_2}) \big)
$$

I know I must be missing something, but I just can't figure out where the minus sign is coming from.

Comment: Remember that $i^2=-1$?

Comment: OH yup that's it, thank you! Also thanks for the formatting, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall from the definition of $i$ that $i^2=-1$.